# Tips for parsing Standard Input in JavaScript

Tags: array, tips, parsing, javascript

I've been doing quite a few code golf recently and I realised that a lot of times, I have to do something involving list.

Most of the times lists are space-separated or comma-separated values in the first argument (`argv[2]`), and the return value should also be a space/comma-separated string.

Are there any tips for converting comma/space-separated to array and back to comma/space-separated values ?

Here's what I know so far:

#### Array => String

```
["foo","bar","baz"].join() // Default argument is ","
["foo","bar","baz"].join` ` // ES6 backtick syntax
["foo","bar","baz"]+"" // Equivalent of toString(): return comma-separated values
```

#### String => Array

```
"foo,bar,baz".split`,` // ES6 backtick syntax
```

So are they other shorter ways of doing it or problem-specific solutions that doesn't require conversion from string to array and back to string ?

Comment: Why not simply take input and return output as lists?

Comment: What do you mean ?

Comment: Your problem seems to be stemming from getting a list in text form, and wanting to return a list as text form, but according to default I/O rules, you can write a function that deals with actual lists.

Answer (score 2):

### `eval`

For array of numbers, `eval` may work.

```javascript
s.split(',')
eval(`[${s}]`)
```

Although code above is a bit longer, but there are some extra benefits via `eval`:

- `eval` returns `number[]` instead of `string[]`, and you can add them easier.
- `eval` provide an extra `()` pair. You may write some codes in the `eval` string, in the `eval` brackets, and also after the `eval`.

Answer (score 1):

### String.prototype.replace

If you want a simple `Array#map`, you may use `String#replace` instead.

```javascript
s.split`,`.map(v=>f(v))+''      // comma split and join
s.replace(/[^,]+/g,v=>f(v))     // comma separated
s.replace(/\w+/g,v=>f(v))       // comma separated

s.split` `.map(v=>f(v)).join` ` // space split and join
s.replace(/\S+/g,v=>f(v))       // space separated
```

`String#replace` may be shorter if you can find a short RegExp. `/[^,]+/` is a bit longer, but if `/\w+/` is acceptable, it could be shorter.

But be notice that the 2nd parameter of replace callback is the position by character instead of position in array.

You may also use some capture groups to parse the string in it.